# How to run perl scripts (via BAT file) on a different server than the one I'm on?

Tags: sql-server, windows, perl, permissions, batch-file

On a windows server, I have a lot of perl scripts that insert data into a sqlserver database.  They get invoked via sql agent jobs that launch .bat files

Everything co-exists on the one machine \\oldserver

Changes in company policy require me to split my system up so the database is on \\dbserver and the perl interpreter, scripts, and supporting files all live on \\appserver

**What do I have to do in order to have my \\dbserver-based sql agent fire off .bat files on \\appserver so each bat file runs as if it were actually started on \\appserver**? (ie. using perl installed on \\appserver, has access to \\appserver windows environment settings like PERL5LIB, etc)?

---

Each BAT file looks something like:

```
@echo off
d:
cd project\foo\scripts\myscript.pl
```

Each perl script looks something like:

```
#!/perl/bin
use warnings;
use inHouseLibrary; # via PERL5LIB Env variable on \\\appserver
#[snip]

my $incoming = <path to local folder>;
my $archive  = <path to some other local folder>;

my $config;
$config = do $config_file or die;

foreach my $file ( <files in local folder>){
   #do database-related stuff involving the contents of the file
   File::Copy->move($file, $archive . $file);
}
```

(I'm aware of the [DRY Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) violation. That's just debt I have to carry right now)

---

In case it's relevant:

- \\dbserver has SqlServer 9.0 (2005)
- \\appserver has activestate perl v5.10.1 MSWin32-x86-multithread
- Both machines have windows server 2008 R2 Standard

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using Windows Remote Shell or Windows Powershell, or you could use SSH.

With SSH, the syntax would be:

```
    ssh login@hostname '<command>'
```

The windows PowerShell tutorial is here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

There is also a utility included in sysinternals called 'PsExec' that you might find useful, located here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553